# Is this the way to display data of Parse Objects in recycler View correct?

Tags: android, object, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I have had people recommend two different ways of doing this leaving me confused.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser>query=ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.include("addressPointer");
        query.getInBackground(currentUser.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                 if (e==null){
                     List<ParseAddress> list=parseUser.getList("addressPointer");
                     if (list!=null){
                         for (ParseAddress address:list){
                           //Load data and add to mAdapter. This is where Im confused
                         }
                         mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     }else {
                         Log.d(TAG, "address are 0");
                         Toast.makeText(MyAddress.this, "You have no addresses saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 }else {Log.d(TAG, "error "+e.getMessage());}}});
```

So from what I have seen, I have two options, one is to define an object called AppAddress() in which I can load data from the object and then add it to the adapter like this

```
//In onCreate
List<AppAddress> mAddressList=null;
//In the for loop.
AppAddress mAddress=new AppAddress();
mAddress.setName(address.getName());
mAddress.setCity(address.getCity());
mAddress.setPinCode(address.getPinCode());
mAddress.setPhoneNumber(address.getNumber());
mAddress.setAddress(address.getAddress());
mAddressList.add(mAddress);
```

Or I forget about my custom object class called AppAddress and use my sublcass called ParseAddress that I have already defined and using to get the data from "Address" object. In that case code will be like this

```
List<ParseAddress> mList=null;
//In the for loop
mList=new ArrayList<>();
mList.add(address);
```

IN both cases, my recyclerView will change from public `MyAddressAdapter(Context context, List<AppAddress> list)` to `public MyAddressAdapter(Context context, List<ParseAddress> list)`and I fill in the data in the onBindViewHolder() function. Im able to do both but which one would be better assuming the recyclerView will have buttons to 'edit' and 'delete' these "Address" class objects.

EDIT: So I guess I will stick to the first method then. As of now Im defining the getters and setters and moving data by that way.

ParseObject--> AppAddress --> RecyclerView row --> User edits and changes data in AppAddress entity--> Update associated parse object. This is the flow I will be using. For the last step to work, I will need to make setter and getter for the original ParseObject (ParseAddress) as well correct?

EDIT EDIT : Both methods will work but the first one allows more flexibility in the future as the App Address object can now even be a combination of one or more parse objects or have separate properties associated with it. Credits to Andrey Elizarov. Apart from the data, I am passing Parse Object's object id and recreating the object with createWithNoData("Address", "objectId)

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are correct in terms of immutability as long as you use deep copy of original objects.
But for the sake of splitting responsability I'd go with first one. But if it's simple two-lines project second one is enough.

UPDATE:
In general second method implies that your business object (ParseAddress in this case) will never ever be changed. It will hold the same fields and methods indefinitely. Like 100 years from now) But in real world there is always possibility of future refactoring.

Conceptually you have two different entities. One to store in Parse, another to operate with, show in RecycleView in your case.

Ask yourself - how will I proceed if it will be necessary to add one convenient and useful method in this class? Do I really need all original fields from ParseAddress? Should this fields be typed and formatted this way?

Also such distinction will make code cleaner and more readable. On the other hand creating objects is not too expensive operation.

You can even make constructor that will make deep copy invisibly.

```
AppAddress ad = new AppAddress(parseAddress);
```

And add/remove setters/getters in AppAddress as you like. How cool is that %)

EDIT:
Depending on your goals you can make accessors or stick to constructors. I personally do not expose objects'  internal state if do no not forced by some framework and do not provide setters if do not have to. 
Also with lot of setters it is easy to forget something. And constructor allows you to literally construct) object in one place.

One minor(?) advantage of using AppAddress class is that you can incapsulte all validation and string formating logic in it. I am implying there will be such a logic since you working with addresses.
But if this two classes will duplicate functionallity it is easier to eliminate middle AppAddress and leave decoupling for tomorrow when you'll have to add some behaviour that  ParseAddress do not suppose to have.

UPDATE:
feel free to accept answer if you feel it's helpful)

Comment: I plan to release this app in the play store and build extensively on it. Hopefully get external funding as well so I need to keep 'best practices' in mind. Can you tell what exactly is wrong with using the second method ? If i use the first method, then I will have to transfer the objectID and query for the object if i want to reference the exact one again.